# How to duplicate JavaScript inside the for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Consider the following code:

```
<body>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {

        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model[i].Name)

        <button id="open" onclick="activate()" class="btn btn-default">Open</button>
        <div id="box" style="display: none">
            Hi @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].Name)
        </div>


    }
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function activate() {
            $('#box').show();

        }

    </script>
</body>
```

As you can see from my code above, when an user click "Open", the div with ID "box" will be shown, however, what I want is to show multiple div id Box, depends on the For-loop. At the moment, the button can be generated successfully, but there's only one box because both refer to the same ID "box". Is it possible to duplicate or add index into the id="box", so the number of box will be depends on the for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While duplicating the JS is one way of achieving this it's not very DRY. Given your current code you will also encounter problems using duplicate `id` attributes as they must be unique within the DOM.

A better solution would be to instead genericise the HTML and JS such that one single event handler will work for all instances of that HTML structure.

To do that you can use `class` attributes to group your HTML elements and select them in jQuery. Something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.open').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.box').show();
  });
});
```

```css
.box { display: none; }
```

```html
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => item.Name)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.Name)

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default open">Open</button>
  <div class="box">
    Hi @Html.TextBoxFor(model => item.Name)
  </div>
}
```

Note that you're using an editable textbox for the greeting; presumably that should just be `Hi @item.Name`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I actually managed to add index into it so something like <div id="box@(i)"> and managed to get all things work, what do you think is the weakness of my approach? Thanks

Comment: Using incremental id attributes is another solution, although again suffers from not being DRY and also a maintenance pain. The approach I showed you above is easily extensible and only relies on 3 lines of code for all event handlers on all button elements.

Comment: Thank you so much!